# Скопировать содержимое из одного PDF в другой

Tags: delphi, pdf

Использую `Synopse` для работы с `PDF`. Как можно программно содержимое одного файла добавить в конец другого файла?. Либо же какими - нибудь другими средствами или методами. Не платными. Использую среду Delphi XE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Synopse` не позволяет работать с уже готовыми pdf-файлами. Как указывается на [официальном форуме](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=982) - это библиотека для создания (записи) pdf, а не для их чтения. В списке todo у авторов такой задачи тоже нет.

Для объединения нескольких pdf в один можно воспользоваться несколькими средствами, наиболее популярным (на мой взгляд) является [Coherent](http://community.coherentpdf.com/), позволяющая работать с параметрами командной строки.
Вам необходима следующая команда, описанная на сайте Coherent:

`cpdf one.pdf two.pdf three.pdf -o merged.pdf`

Естественно, желательно указывать полные пути к файлам, включая сам cpdf.

Примечание: желательно прочитать FAQ с сайта Coherent внизу страницы.

Comment: а  Coherent поддерживает кириллицу в командах ?  меня вот такая команда `cpdf -add-text "Привет мир" one.pdf -o two.pdf` выдает ошибку

Comment: Это вы пытаетесь в консоли написать, или передаете параметрами в командной строке программно?

Comment: да,  консоли выдает ошибку. Но когда я пытаюсь передать в программе в `ShellExecuteEx` в параметрах например вот такую строку текста `C:\\Downloads\\Новая папка` , то в документ pdf попадает только `C:\\Downloads\\`

Comment: @gregor Консоль работает с OEM-кодировкой, что может некорректно восприниматься приложением в плане национальных символов. Параметры стоит попробовать заключать в двойные кавычки `"`, иначе каждый пробел будет считаться новым переданным параметром. С исполняемыми файлами лучше работать через CreateProcess, а не ShellExecute.

Comment: Исправил на `CreateProcess`. В итоге получается второй параметр для неё 'cpdf.exe -add-text "file://C:/Users/Greg/Downloads/Новая папка" -topleft 15 -font-size 8 -color "blue" D:\Projects\Data\20160505141418867.pdf -o D:\Projects\Data\20160505141418870.pdf'` Результат на выходе `file://C:/Users/Greg/Downloads/`

Comment: http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/node54.html
 Требуется кодирование. Если предложенное решение Вас не устраивает - можно попробовать подобрать другое, их должно быть много, не зацикливайтесь только на этом, оно было дано исключительно как пример с опиской "на мой взгляд".